# Javascript onClick function with parameters

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript function as below:

```
function letMeGo(var1, var2, var3){
    if(var1 == 1 && var2 == 1 && var3 == 1){
        document.getElementById('goOn').href="goOn.php";
    }
}
```

the variables are the return of other functions.

And I need it to be triggered by:

```
<a id="goOn" onclick="letMeGo(var1, var2, var3)">Go On</a>
```

it is not working unless I removed the variable in both, the link and the function.
How can i get it to work with them?

Comment: If the variables are the return of other functions, why not just call the other functions in `letMeGo`?

Comment: not working means what? Did it catch on fire? What is the error message? What is the mystery var1, var2, var3?

Comment: Does this work? `<a id="goOn" onclick="letMeGo(1, 1, 1)">Go On</a> `. If so, then you need to check the values of those three variables before binding that `onClick` handler. That code seems to be absent from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to affect the return of the other functions to global variables (example: `window.myvar1`) and use them instead of your parameters `var1, var2, var3`.

I mean to not use any parameters in your function `letMeGo` and inside it, replace var1 by its global variable equivalent, and so on for var2 and var3.